# Помогите разобрать отельный случай задачи

Tags: c++, олимпиада

*При m >= k, нужно найти C из n по k, но с такими ограничениями так нельзя :( как задачу можно решить без факториала ?*

Текст задачи :

Егор хочет оформить свою гостиную в стиле постмодерн с элементами барокко. Дизайнер предложил ему оформить градиентное освещение – вставить в специальную нишу ровно
k
лампочек так, чтобы они шли в одну линию, а интенсивность света строго увеличивалась слева направо. Чтобы эта линия смотрелась плавно и гармонично, необходимо чтобы мощности лампочек увеличивались строго на единицу при переходе от одной лампочки к другой слева направо. Будем называть степенью освещенности помещения мощность последней лампочки в нише (то есть самой яркой).

Егор любит продумывать все варианты, поэтому ему стало интересно, сколько различных степеней освещенности можно получить, используя имеющиеся у него в запасе лампочки. Лампочки имеются двух видов — одни рассчитаны на определенную мощность, таких у Егора
n
штук, все их мощности известны, для
i
-й лампочки из этой категории она составляет
w
i
. Вторую часть лампочек в количестве
m
штук Егору подарил дизайнер, который и был автором всей этой затеи. Эти лампочки можно отрегулировать под любую целочисленную мощность от
1
до
10
6
.

Помогите Егору и найдите, сколько различных уровней освещенности можно получить.

Формат входных данных
В первой строке даны три числа — число лампочек у Егора
n
(
1
≤
n
≤
10
6
), число лампочек, подаренных дизайнером,
m
(
1
≤
m
≤
10
6
) и количество лампочек в нише
k
(
1
≤
k
≤
10
6
). Во второй строке даны мощности
n
лампочек, мощность
i
-й лампочки составляет
w
i
Ватт (
1
≤
w
i
≤
10
6
).

Формат результата
Выведите единственное число — сколько различных уровней освещенности можно получить.

Примеры
Входные данные

```
8 3 5
1 5 60 58 61 11 27 25
```

Результат работы

```
9
```

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;
typedef  unsigned long long ll;

    ll factorial(ll n) {
        ll res=1;
        while (n > 0) {
            res*=n;
            n--;
        }
        return res;
    }
int main() {
    ll n,m,k;
    cin >> n >> m >> k;
    vector<ll> a(1000005);
    ll maxn = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ; i <= n;i++ ) {
        ll c;
        cin >> c;
        maxn = max(maxn , c);
        a[c]++;
    }
    if( m >= k) { \\Заменить этот кусок на что-то эффективное 
        ll pre = (factorial(9))/ ( factorial(k)*(factorial(9-k))); \\ C из n по k
        cout <<pre;
        return 0;
    }
    vector<ll> podsum(1000005);

    for(ll i = 1; i<= k;i++) {
        podsum[1] += a[i] ;
    }

    for(ll i = 2; i <= 1000005;i++) {
        podsum[i] = podsum[i - 1] - a[i - 1] + a[i + k - 1];
    }
    ll res = 0;
    for(int i = 1 ;i <=1000005;i++) {
        if (podsum[i] + m >= k) {
            res++;
        }
    }
    cout << res;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Переименуйте вопрос так, чтобы было сразу понятно, какая именно у вас проблема.

Comment: вы точно уверены что вашего `ll` хватит чтобы посчитать факториал для 10^6 ? и почему вообще в коде присутствует константа 9

Comment: @teran , вы правы, не хватит

Comment: @teran, как я понял в задаче при  m >= k , нужно найти все возможные сочетания длинны k ,  а 9 , потому что на выбор есть 9 чисел (1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9) Хотя , возможно, вы имели ввиду мой плохой стиль кода

Comment: не вижу в задаче ничего про 9. вы бы свое решение словами бы объяснили лучше.

Comment: `10 6` - это миллион так скопипащен. Судя по размеру `a` - это должно быть понятно. Откуда тогда речь про 9?

Comment: В комбинаторике сочетанием из n по k называется набор k элементов, выбранных из данного множества, содержащего n различных элементов.  Я руководствовался этим соображением

Comment: Это определение вряд ли имеет отношение к данной задаче.

Comment: @MBo , а как , в таком случае , следует решать данную задачу ?

Comment: Текст задачи не читал, но вы считаете факториалы отдельно в числителе и знаменателе. Так не надо делать. Лучше на каждом шаге цикла считать очередной множитель в произведении

Comment: Используя `unsigned long long`, можно посчитать сочетания C_n^m максимум до n==63. С вашими числами это все нереально. Нужен кардинально иной алгоритм...

Comment: Дайте, если можно, URL задачи (проверяющей системы).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если `m>=k`, то возможно создать непрерывную серию, кончающуюся на любое число из допустимого диапазона, поэтому в этом случае ответ `1000001 - k`

Иначе нужно посчитать, сколько можно создать непрерывных серий, а для этого узнать, сколько в диапазоне `end = k..1000000` (точнее, до значения `maxlamp + k`) существует скользящих окон длиной `k` с концом в `end`, содержащих не менее `k-m` лампочек традиционной ориентации.

В простейшем случае можно просто пройти в цикле по указанному диапазону. Если значение лампочки выходит из окна, уменьшить  счётчик. Если входит - увеличить счётчик. Количество шагов, на которых счётчик `>=  k-m` и есть решение.

При небольшом количестве обычных лампочек выгоднее, конечно, пройти только по тем местам, где они есть

Вот примитивное решение, оптимизация за автором.

```
n = 8
m = 3
k = 5
l = [1, 5, 60, 58, 61, 11, 27, 25]
a = set(l)
maxx = max(l)
if m >= k :
    print(1000001 - k)
else:
    count = 0
    res = 0
    l = 1
    for r in range(1, k+1):
        if r in a:
            count += 1

    #переберём правые концы интервалов длиной k
    for r in range(k+1, min(1000000, maxx + k + 1)): 
        if count >= k - m:   #добавив m универсальных ламп, заполним окно длиной k
            res += 1
        if l in a:    #обычная лампа выходит из интервала слева
            count -= 1
        if r in a:    #обычная лампа входит в интервал справа
            count += 1
        l += 1
    print(res)
```